# How do I apply knockout validation inside foreach binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

My goal is to apply a knockout required validator on an input that is part of a collection on a viewmodel and made visible inside a foreach binding. Here's what I have so far - errors always evals to 0, not sure where I'm going wrong here.

```
   var vm = {

    myCollection: myCollection,  <-- im binding the foreach onto this property, and consists of a collection of Items



    submit: function () {
        if (vm.errors().length == 0) {
            alert('Thank you.');   <-- errors is always 0
        } else {
            vm.errors.showAllMessages();
            app.showMessage('There were some errors...', '');
        }
    }
};


 var Item = function (data) {

        self.name = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

 }

vm["errors"] = ko.validation.group(vm);


<div data-bind="foreach: myCollection">
<input type="text" 
data-bind="value: name,
validationOptions: {errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A rare fix from me..

Added this to the Item model,

```
    self["itemerrors"] = ko.validation.group(self);
```

then walked the array in the submit method of the vm

```
     ko.utils.arrayForEach(vm.mycollection(), function (name) {
          name.itemerrors.showAllMessages();
     });
```

works a treat

Comment: Or configure the group do be deep and then self.errors.showAllMessages(); on the parent

Comment: I'll try that, do you configure deep when you do the applyBinding?

Comment: Its a configure of the validation lib https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration